# How to make Make *not* print "recipe for target failed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm building a Makefile for a sequence of compiles to show progressive output differences to be used to synchronize with the examples in a tutorial. Some of those runs generates error codes, but since that is part of the definition of the "problem" the message output by make ("*Makefile:15: recipe for target `run3' failed*") when a target fails kind of gets in the way.

I know about ignoring the error code, but is it possible to suppress that output? Preferable from within the Makefile.

On a similar note, is it possible to suppress the message of entering and leaving subdirectories from within the Makefile (equivalent to '--no-print-directory')?

And, yes, I'm satisfied with a GNU Make answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, after some googling the answer is in the [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets%20GNU%20Make%20Manual). The special targets .SILENT and .IGNORE did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: They did? Neither appears to turn off the `recipe for target blah/blah.foo failed` message.

Comment: Yes, if both .SILENT: and .IGNORE: are specified without prerequisites then the message is suppressed. Note that the message seems to have been added after 3.82, it is in the Cygwin-version but not in the official 3.82 sources. The message also appears in version 4.0.

Comment: Beside `.IGNORE` a `-` at the beginning of the recipe line’s text (after the initial tab) along with `.SILENT` also works for me. My GNU Make version is 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want I would use `--silent --ignore-errors --no-print-directory` GNU `make` switches and redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` (`2>/dev/null`) commands in the makefile

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that can be used from within the Makefile.

Comment: Does setting `MAKEFLAGS = --silent --ignore-errors --no-print-directory` help?

Comment: Thanks, Jack. Not really, unless you can set it from within the Makefile. I am assuming you mean as an environment variable?